# Definition of homogeneous distribution.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I ran into the following definition:

If $u$ is a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $u$ is called homogeneous of order $m$ if $u(\lambda x) = \lambda^m u(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. But $u$ is not necessarily a function on $\mathbb{R}^d$, so how to make sense of the notation $u(x)$?

Comment: the notation $u(x)$ is justified by the fact that even if distributions are continuous linear forms on the space of test functions, they are also localized on $\mathbb{R}^d$, you probably already defined distributions with support $(-1,1)^d$ which are zero for any test function whose support is outside of $(-1,1)^d$. and you can extract some part of the distribution by multiplying the test functions onto which it acts by a $C^\infty$ approximation of the indicator function of this support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining $\phi_\lambda(x)=\phi(\lambda x)$ for smooth $\phi$, the requirement is
$$
u(\phi_{\lambda})=\lambda^{-m-d}u(\phi)\quad\forall\phi\in C_0^{\infty}.
$$
If $u$ happens to be a continuous function (and hence $u(\phi)=\int u(x)\phi(x)$), this is equivalent to what you wrote.